# Walker with different output on submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I have two different submenus in my main menu. I do not want the same output on both submenus from my walker, since I am going to implement two different functions on each submenu button.

How can I get two different outputs so I can output for example `<button @click="function1">First Button</button>` on the first submenu and `<button @click="function2">Second Button</button>` on the second submenu?

menu.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu'       => 'Main Navigation',
        'container'  => false,
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="main-menu">%3$s</ul>',
        'walker'         => new m2o_walker_nav_menu()
));
```

functions.php

```
class m2o_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<button>First Button</button><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

I tried using conditionals with `$depth`. But it seems that it is the same depth, so the output will be the same on both. Anyone know why the `$depth` is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to output different buttons relating to the depth of the menu entry. I guess in the simplest way, you could just check the `$depth` variable and change the text of the button.

**Quick Solution:**

```
public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $buttontext = 'First Button';

    if ($depth == 2) {
        $buttontext = 'Second Button';
    }

    if ($depth == 3) {
        $buttontext = 'Third Button';
    }

    if ($depth == 4) {
        $buttontext = 'Fourth Button';
    }

    $output .= "\n$indent <button>$buttontext</button><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
}
```

You could extend that with more variables (for example the onClick action). Or the cleaner approach would be to create a new method inside m2o_walker_nav_menu that returns the representing button variables based on their depth.

**Cleaner Solution:**

```
public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $buttondata = self::getButtonData($depth);

    $output .= "\n" . $indent . "<button onClick='" . $buttondata['action'] . "'>" . $buttondata['text'] . "</button><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
}

public static function getButtonData($depth) {

    $buttons = [
        [
            'text' => 'First Button',
            'action' => 'myFirstFunction'
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Second Button',
            'action' => 'mySecondFunction'
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Third Button',
            'action' => 'myThirdFunction'
        ]
    ];

    return $buttons[$depth];
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is untested, because i don't have wordpress installed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: On your quick solution. I thought using depth too, but apparently they use the same depth so both will be "First Button".

Comment: And on your cleaner solution I get a syntax error which I can't clean. `syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Comment: i made two mistakes in the cleaner solution:
1. i forgot to put the keyword `function` to it.
2. the output of start_lvl() was escaped in a bad way.
i edited my answer. try it again pls.

Comment: The clean solution runs now. But still, they appear to have the same depth so same button appears twice :/

Comment: Thats interesting. Did you try to specify the depth of your navigation inside wp_nav_menu()? Try to set it to 4 or something. Maybe there is a bug in wp_nav_menu() and the $depth will be set correctly when you set the depth option accordingly.

Comment: I did not have any depth set in the wp_nav_menu(). But it should work with the default 0, right? Setting it to a different value did not help though.

Comment: Yeah, it should default to 0, but i was just curious if the wp_nav_menu() had a bug or something. Its strange, because in every example i can find the $depth variable works the way it should. I don't understand why its not incremented in your case. Did you try to add the start_el() method and output the $depth there? just to test if the depth gets increased on this method or if it stays 0.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/

Comment: It does get increased in the start_el() method. I still can't figure out what is wrong, it SHOULD work! :(